# Storing CoreData objects into NSDictionary or NS Array

Tags: core-data

I am trying to store the Output of `[Sectioninfo Objects]` into an array

```
NSArray *currentCategory = [sectionInfo objects];
```

Although the OutPut that i get on NSLOG is as Follows :

```
"<Catalogue: 0x6da1d20> (
    entity: Catalogue;
    id: 0x6da1090 <x-coredata://894839B1-B485-4D64-8D46-99E388F00225/Catalogue/p3> ;
    data: {\n    comments = nil;\n
                 email = nil;\n
                 name = Shorts;\n
                 phone = 0;\n
                 picture = <ffd8ffe0 00104a46 49460001 01000001 00010000 ffe10058 45786966 00004d4d 002a0000 00080002 01120003 00000001 0001>;\n
                 price = 77;\n
                 shop = Shop;\n
                 website = nil;\n})"
```

I am Interested only in the Data Part

How Can i Extract it The Data Part only  ?
& then I can add it to NSArray

Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question is tagged core-data, I assume you are talking about the section information you get from a `NSFetchedResultsController` via

```
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
```

If that is the case, then the section info protocol specifies that `objects` returns an array of objects in that section.  This array of objects will hold actual objects, just like the array of objects you get back from executing a fetch.

You can, thus, access them just like you would any other object.  Hopefully, you have a subclass, so you can access the object via the appropriate properties.

Otherwise, you can use the KVC methods.  From your log output, I assume `data` is a property of your object (probably a string).

```
NSArray *sectionObjects = [sectionInfo objects];
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionObjects.count];
for (NSManagedObject *object in sectionObjects) {
    NSString *data = [object valueForKey:@"data"];
    [dataArray addObject:data];
}
```

Or, you could do it more succinctly as:

```
NSArray *dataArray = [[sectionInfo objects] valueForKey:@"data"];
```

which returns an array with the result of applying the key to each object in the receiver.

Comment: First Thank you for your Help,although "data" is not part of my properties , my properties starts from "comments", email,...           The First 2 Lines {"<Catalogue: 0x6da1d20> (
    entity: Catalogue;
    id: 0x6da1090 <x-coredata://894839B1-B485-4D64-8D46-99E388F00225/Catalogue/p3> ;
    data: {\n} , i have no idea what are they , or how to get rid of them , by the way i get the same when i try fetch request

Comment: OK, so what is your entity description, and where are you getting this object?  Of course you will have the same thing when you fetch, because you are getting the same objects, just grouped by section.  Provide your entity description, as well as your fetch request.

Comment: Well I solved the Problem for displaying my objects, all i had to do assing to the Correct NSOBJECT .it works fine from display point of view , although from point of View NSFecthResultschangecontent is not called properly as the tableview is refreshed at all

Comment: Great!  If your solution is completely different from this answer, then provide it as the answer, and accept it.  That way, others struggling with a similar problem may discover your insight.  Self-answered questions are encouraged on SO.